# Open a Progressive Web App from a native Android app

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I need to launch a Progressive Web App (PWA) from a native Android app (a custom Android launcher).

I didn't find any documentation how PWA work in Android.

The Intent to run another native Android app is the following:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
```

How a PWA can be launched?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Bubblewrap

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap

From the link:

Bubblewrap is a set of tools and libraries designed to help developers to create, build and update projects for Android Applications that launch Progressive Web App (PWA) using Trusted Web Activity (TWA).

Comment: According to the TWA concept, a website should store the information about the launching application. So it's not possible to open ANY PWA from the app by using this technique? 

I'm developing a custom Android launcher and users want to launch PWA by clicking icons on a desktop. That's why I'm searching for the underlying technology (there's another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686355/). I am very disappointed that there's no simple way to work with PWAs similar to how Android deals with native apps. At least there's no docs!

Comment: You can open any website this way, but you won't have some of the TWA benefits, like being able to hide browser chrome. Are you trying to open someone else's PWA in your app?

Comment: You are right, I'd like to open someone else's PWA in the app, in the same way the default system launcher does. Looks like I need to look into the system launcher's source code (if it's still open source).